# particles sit above collision object when "size deflect" is active

Tags: particles, physics, collision

[image: particles at rest "on" plane]I have a basic particle system with a cube emitter, uv sphere particles, and a plane as the ground with "collision" on. when running the sim, particles sit half way in the floor. If "size deflect" is active the particles stop far above the ground plane.
please help

Edit: picture is particles "at rest on" the ground plane

blender versions 2.90 + 2.90.1
macOS 10.15.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/161762/75504

Comment: I did read that, and managed to use some version of his workaround. see below

Comment: My solution has been as is shown here - (See halfway down to a heading - 
"A few points should be made here -") - 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193451/trampoline-like-effect-using-cloth-modifier/194269#194269 - There'd be no shapekeys or bouncing to contend with, just align your copied ground higher to sit just under the particles.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround which was just playing with a combination of particle render scale (0.009 turned out to work here) and object scale until something sat at the right level. This really doesn't seem like the right way to solve this though...

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, I looked for a tangible solution for more than a day. The work around of raising a copy of the plane is a good hack solution, but it seems to me that there must be reliable built in solution that should work without a hack. I got things to work in one test and then can't get it to work in an other one. It's almost as if there's an offset value hidden somewhere. If I move a particle in a collection or if I apply a material to the emitter things go weird. I also tried the Molecular Script, I had no luck up to know.

It would be great to know what causes this so that it can be bypassed during production.

Blender 2.90.1 Mac 10.14.6

[image: [![Size deflect problem][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0FrR.png]

Comment: I can't help but feel that blender for MacOS just doesn't work very well at all. I've only ever used it on Macs, but I can't imagine the software has gotten as far as it has being this janky for everyone. I could just be doing it wrong tho idk..